# GitHub Action On Pull Request Error with inputs

Tags: github-actions

I am new on **GitHub Actions** and I am trying to migrate some **Azure DevOps Pipelines**. One of the pipelines that I am migrating run when a ***Pull Request*** is created and can also be run manually. For that purpose on the pipeline yaml I have a parameter defined with a default value which is used when it is executed by a ***Pull Request***

```
parameters:
- name: VERBOSE
  displayName: 'Verbose'
  type: boolean
  default: false
```

For the **GitHub Action** yaml, I wrote the following:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      Verbose:
        description: 'Will output messages which could be useful for debugging.'
        default: false
        required: true
        type: boolean
jobs:
  check:
    name: 'Check'
    runs-on: ${{ env.virtualMachine }}
    steps:
      - name: 'Check out repository code'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: 'Nuget Tool Installer'
        uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
      - name: 'Restore Project'
        working-directory: ${{ env.projectPath }}
        run: nuget restore ${{ env.project }} -PackagesDirectory ${{ env.projectPath }}
      - name: 'Setup .Net'
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.dotNet }}
      - name: 'Build Project'
        working-directory: ${{ env.projectPath }}
        run: dotnet build ${{ env.project }} --configuration ${{ env.buildConfiguration }}
      - name: 'Run no verbose'
        if: ${{ input.Verbose == false }}
        working-directory: ${{ env.workingDirectory }}
        run: ./xxxxx
      - name: 'Run verbose'
        if: ${{ input.Verbose == true }}
        working-directory: ${{ env.workingDirectory  }}
        run: ./xxxxx -Verbose
```

But when it is executed, the following error is displayed:

> Error in if-expression: "if: ${{ input.Verbose == false }}" (Unavailable context: input)

Seems that I can not use inputs for actions triggered by ***Pull Requests***. Do you know if there is another way to define it? Or should I wrote two **GitHub Actions**:

- One for Pull Request
- One for Manual Trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that "triggering the pipeline manually" means that you want to run your workflow from the `Run workflow` button in `Actions` tab

[image: Run workflow manually]

If it's the case you have to use [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) **not [`workflow_call`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_call)**.

Then for your `Run no verbose` step you want to run it when:

- You trigger the workflow from a PR: `${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}`
- **Or**, you are running the manual workflow with `Verbose==false`

So you might be looking for something like:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - development
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Verbose:
        description: 'Will output messages which could be useful for debugging.'
        default: false
        required: true
        type: boolean
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Run no verbose'
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' || inputs.Verbose == false  }}
      run: echo "not so verbose"

    - name: 'Run verbose'
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && inputs.Verbose == true  }}
      run: echo "SO VERBOSE"
```